# cannot add the TradeRequest with server API in MT5

Tags: plugins, trading, metatrader5

I am developing mt5 (MetaTrader 5) plugin. But I have one problem. I tried to make the TradeRequest and add it to request queue using server API, but I cannot find any additional request in request queue. The value of recode is 0 (it means successful). I confused. Why not?
In addition, what is the difference between IMTOrder and IMTRrequest? Which class is used for trading operation? Thanks for considering my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had same question and I tried to make new order using Server API.
Finally I solved it using manager API.
Please use DealerSend of Manager API.